# How to read data from ThingSpeak for esp8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am trying to read data from thingspeak for esp8266 but I couldn't do that. There is a link:
GET https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/123456/fields/1.json?api_key=***********&results=2
But how can I use it?

Comment: are you able to connect to some other website like stackexchange.com?

Comment: I don't know. But probably I can.

Comment: I believe Thingspeak supports MQTT. That would be preferable in my opinion.

Comment: How are you doing that? Please post your code

Comment: @StarCat What is MQTT.

Comment: MQTT is a message protocol for sending small messages to and from IoT devices like sensor values, status messages or receiving commands. It's simple to implement and very reliable. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-with-esp8266.html) is an introduction to using an ESP8266 with Thingspeak and MQTT. It might work for you.

Comment: use ESP8266HttpClient library. see the examples.

Comment: check out https://shiftr.io/try to get an idea what MQTT is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I directly code the esp8266 with thingSpeak library. Anyone who is interested look here:[How to read data from thingspeak](https://electronics-project-hub.com/how-to-read-data-from-thingspeak-arduino-esp8266-nodemcu/). And it worked. Thanks for your replies.